# Returning a promise from a reducer with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using [this starter kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and the code below can be found on [this fork](https://github.com/elduderino87/react-redux-starter-kit).

The counter component:

```
export const Counter = (props) => (
  <div style={{ margin: '0 auto' }} >
    <h2>Counter: {props.counter}</h2>
    <button className='btn btn-default' onClick={props.double}>
      Double (Async)
    </button>
  </div>
)
Counter.propTypes = {
  counter     : React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  double : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  increment   : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Counter
```

And the container component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { increment, double } from '../modules/counter'

import Counter from '../components/Counter'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment : () => increment(1),
  double: () => double()
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counter : state.counter
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```

The actions:

```
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT'
export const COUNTER_DOUBLE = 'COUNTER_DOUBLE'
// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export const increment = (value = 1) => {
  return {
    type: COUNTER_INCREMENT,
    payload: value
  }
}
export const double = (value = 0) => {
  return {
    type: COUNTER_DOUBLE,
    payload: value
  }
}

const doubleAsync = (state) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(increment(state))
        resolve()
      }, 200)
    })
  }
}

export const actions = {
  increment,
  double
}


const ACTION_HANDLERS = {

  [COUNTER_INCREMENT]: function (state, action) {
    return state + action.payload
  },
  [COUNTER_DOUBLE]: (state, action) => {
    return doubleAsync()

    }
  }
}
```

And the reducers:

```
const initialState = 0
export default function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]
  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

However the `COUNTER_DOUBLE` action handler does not seem to update the view, and nothing is rendered. I get this warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `counter` of type `function`
>   supplied to `Counter`, expected `number`.

I realise I've defined a number `propType` and returning the promise function leads to this error. I've even tried to modify `mapDispatchToProps` to return the executed promise function to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

I've searched here and the consensus seems to be to use redux-thunk to wrap the promise with a function that executed immediately but I'm having difficulty getting this to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default redux expects actions to be plain objects. If you want to write some asynchronous code and return a promise you need to use some kind of middleware, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) would be a great option.

The README page of redux-thunk is actually quite documented, and there is a full example there. Basically you need to apply the redux-thunk middleware to your store like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

In addition I suggest you read the redux documentation about [async action creators](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html), it has some great examples.